# Looking for a JSON editor to embed in Meteor--preferably with multiple selections/cursors

Tags: json, editor, meteor, highlighting, ace-editor

I'm looking for a good JSON editor, especially with multiple selections/cursors to embed in my Meteor project.  I am wondering if one is already available for Meteor.  I've seen this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors but Meteor uses Handlebars a templating framework, and I'm not sure how a JSON editor would mesh with Handlebars.  Any ideas?

EDIT:  I'd like to use ACE from Mozilla/Cloud 9.  Any ideas on how to integrate this with Meteor?

EDIT:  Currently, my code looks like this (in separate files):

```
<script src="http://d1n0x3qji82z53.cloudfront.net/src-min-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<template name="canvas">
<div id="canvas">
{{#each jsons}}
<div draggable="true" class="json" id="json_{{_id}}">
    {{title}}<br/>
    <input type="file" accept="text/json"/>
    <hr/>
    <div class="editor" id="text_{{_id}}">{{data}}</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
</div>
</template>

var editor = ace.edit("text_"+json_id);
editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

.editor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

One problem I'm having is that when {{data}} is replaced, the editor goes away.  Does anyone know a good way to fix it?  I'm going to try to reinitialize.

EDIT:  Similar question here: [Subscribing to changes in a Collection but not in a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201106/subscribing-to-changes-in-a-collection-but-not-in-a-template)

Here is how I auto subscribe.

```
 Meteor.autosubscribe(function () {
   Meteor.subscribe("jsons");
 });
```

Recreating the ace editor with the mouse action that originally created the editor works, but reinitializing from code (after loading from a FileReader) doesn't seem to be working, the editor disappears with the pretty printed text and it looks like an ordinary div again:

```
    Template.canvas.dragStart();
    $('#json_'+value._id+' input').on('change', function(ev) {
      var target = ev.target != null ? ev.target : ev.srcElement;
      var json_id = value._id;
      _.each(target.files, function(file) {
          var r = new FileReader();
          r.onload = function(e) {
                  Jsons.update({_id: json_id},
                          {$set: {data: JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(e.target.result),null,"\t") }});
                    $('.json')
                            .draggable('disable');
                    var editor = ace.edit("text_"+json_id);
                    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
                    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
          }
          r.readAsText(file);
      });
    });
    $.each(value.inputPorts, Template.canvas.renderPort);
    $.each(value.outputPorts, Template.canvas.renderPort);
```

EDIT:  Also, I'd like the editor to be collaborative multiuser like Meteor is as well.

EDIT:  This looks fantastic: http://asteroid.meteor.com/  where's the source code?
John

Comment: Besed on the last edit, sounds like Etherpad is the way to go.

Comment: Please reduce the case you posted in the question to just the code that is relevant to the question itself - eg. making a multi-user editor with Meteor. Right now I see all kinds of unrelated code like event handlers responding to dragging (why?). It will be easier for people to help you if you simplify the question.

Comment: I agree that the drag events just might be the issue.  I would like to get rid of modes/tools out of the application entirely.  I need some way to drag editors around as I have multiple editors on the page, they overlap etc.  If that affects editing, then I might need to approach the problem differently.  Here's very alpha app: http://jsondemons.meteor.com

Comment: Note that the selection tool (arrow) to the far left of toolbar does the dragging.  Note that the editors go out of edit mode when in < or > mode and one clicks on a box.   This may still be due to dragging.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to select something in the editor and drag it to an input or output port that appears to the left or right of the big boxes (created with < and >), or drag it to another editor and drop on a cursor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=howto) it supports most languages.

Comment: Part of the question is how to get the ace editor initialized when using handlebars.  It doesn't stay up if you initialize the text with {{var_here))